# C# to get accurate client ipv6 public address

Tags: c#, ipv6

Using the below C# to get ipv6 is inaccurate for my test site, when i compare the site https://test-ipv6.com/ ipv6 value is different.

I think how to using C# to get ipv6 value same as the https://test-ipv6.com/ ipv6 value. It is using same client, i curious why i cannot find the ipv6 info, including the headers.

The below code is using .net 5 (C #)

```
HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv6().ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you map an IPv4 to IPv6, the IPv4 is just *represented* as IPv6.

If your client connects using IPv4, then you can't obtain their IPv6 address.